# Cannot find type 'ViewController' in scope. dont know how to do

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

i find cant use vc to transfer data from one viewcontroller to another, the warning error is

```
'Cannot find type 'ViewController' in scope'
```

in my second view controller i have

```
          func switchDidChangeValue(_ value: Bool) {
          let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "KeyboardStoryboard", bundle: nil)
          let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! KeyboardViewController
          let firstVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as! ViewController
          firstVC.delegate = secondVC
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
      }
```

in my first viewcontroller i have

```
protocol SwitchDelegate: AnyObject {
    func switchDidChangeValue(_ value: Bool)
}
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func AutoSpacePressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {

        delegate?.switchDidChangeValue(sender.isOn)
}
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't set the second view controller as the first view controllers delegate. Also, is "second view controller" `KeyboardViewController`?  If so, it seems that it is trying to present itself. This won't work; there needs to be an instance of the view controller first before the code can run.

Comment: It looks like you complicate things in your code. Why you don't present a new vc from within the current vc instead of using nav conttroller? And your *Cannot find type 'ViewController' in scope* issue might be caused by access modifier issue. Try putting `public` keyword in front of your `ViewController` and try again. How exactly is you class hierarchy?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, second view controller is ' keyboardviewcontroller'. and what do you mean a instance of the viewcontroller?

Comment: @some error when use new vc

Comment: I mean that you have some code in KeyboardViewController, but that code creates an instance of KeyboardViewController; for that code to run, an instance of KeyboardViewController must already exist.